# Controlling the white space: distance between headrule, text and footrule inconsistent

Tags: spacing, header-footer

How to control the distance of white space between the rules and the body text?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{.4pt}
}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\lipsum[1-8]
\end{document}
```

As you can see, the distance between headrule and text is inconsistent with the distance between text and footrule.

I'm mostly in need of a solution for the distance between footrule and text, as the solution for headrule and text is already given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40270/how-do-i-increase-the-spacing-between-header-text-and-the-headrule-line-with-f), but doesn't quite work here (?).

See the image:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can adjust the value (length) of `\footskip` or `\headsep` to suit your needs. From the [`layouts` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/layouts) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/layouts/layman.pdf):

[image]

In that sense, maybe the following would suffice:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.4pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{.4pt}
}
\setlength{\footskip}{\dimexpr\headsep+1.5\baselineskip+.4pt}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\lipsum[1-8]
\end{document}
```